# How to Remove Stckiness In Dual Monitors while using 18.04

Tags: multiple-monitors

Up until recently, I was using 16.04 version. But now that I have moved to the latest Ubuntu version 18.04, my mouse stops at the edges and does not go to the second monitor. Any possible solutions to solve this issue? Please help if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your monitor positions they may have changed and your mouse isn't going following the same path it used to. Go into Settings -> Screen Display and you'll see this:

[image: Screen Display]

If monitors are above/below you have to move your mouse up and down. If monitors are left/right you have to move your mouse off the left edge to the right and vice versa.

If this is not the behavior you desire then left click on one monitor and drag it to the appropriate position in relation to the other(s).

Comment: Thanks. But I guess I was asking the issue in 18.04. However, you replied me by giving the  example form 16.04

Comment: @hma66 I gave an example using Unity under Xorg which I presumed to be the same under 18.04 as 16.04. Later today, I will sign in with 18.04 and generate a new screen image. Are you using Gnome when you sign in?

Comment: @hma66 I ran into a snag trying to sign in to other Ubuntu 18.04 desktop environments. I'll retry after I get this problem solved: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029748/upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-lts-to-18-04-lts-5-desktop-environments