# Upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS = 5 desktop environments

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, login, desktop-environments, 18.04

I'm testing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with **Unity** to 18.04 LTS upgrade. After rebooting The first thing I notice is five different desktop environments available at sign in:

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 Five Desktops.jpg]

- I assume the first option is GNOME on Wayland???
- The first and second options result in a movable mouse **cursor** in a sea of purple.
- The third option "Ubuntu" I have no idea if it is supposed to be Wayland or Xorg. Selecting it results in a movable mouse **pointer** in a sea of purple.
- The fourth option I wasn't brave enough to select due to Wayland problems I've read about.
- The last option "Unity" works OK but not what I would call ready for prime-time.

Can anyone explain what option 1 "GNOME" and option 3 "Ubuntu" are supposed to be using for Desktop Environment (DE)?

As I'm running the test in an easily duplicated environment: [Bash script to clone Ubuntu to new partition for testing 18.04 LTS upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade/1028605#1028605), is there something I can do before conversion rather than fixing after conversion? If so I can modify the cloning script to possibly speed up conversion and one less thing to do after conversion.

I would first click the gear to select the Desktop environment and then enter my password. Then the software says "Invalid Password". I retype my password and click the gear icon again to discover my first choice has reset to the default and I have to select my first choice again. The second time I enter my password it is accepted. This happens on all options I tried except for "Unity" which accepted my password the first time.

Comment: 1st gnome is on Wayland and 1st ubuntu is on Xorg, you can always know the running display server by typing `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` after logging in

Comment: @SkanderBejaoui I'm familiar with finding the DE environment **after** you sign in. The problem here is you **cannot** sign in. If the first Ubuntu is on Xorg, how is it different than the `Unity` which is the last option and uses `X11` as well?

Comment: well I did have a login loop with X11 after upgrading from 17.10 and had to reinstall, maybe a bug to report?

Comment: @SkanderBejaoui I'm only interested in running `Unity` which works fine (I'm typing with it now). I wanted to try out Gnome to see how dual screen configuration looked in order to answer a question for another user here in AU. I'm already subscribed to about 20 bug reports and I wouldn't want to file a new one for something not that important to me. Thanks for your time commenting though.